# Handling Slider Thumb Drag With IsMoveToPointEnabled

Tags: c#, wpf

In WPF, I'm able to capture mouse clicks in a Slider having IsMoveToPointEnabled by using this (the events won't trigger otherwise)

```
SeekBar.AddHandler(Slider.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(base.SeekBar_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown), true);
SeekBar.AddHandler(Slider.PreviewMouseDownEvent, new MouseButtonEventHandler(base.SeekBar_PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp), true);
```

Now I'm having more issues with tracking thumb drag. I'm listening to DragStarted and DragCompleted. The issue is that when you click on the Thumb, it raises events in this order: PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown, PreviewMouseLeftButtonUp, and DragStarted.

In a media player seekbar, this causes a seek operation (or a fraction of a second causing a small visual glitch) when you cliick the thumb, and then it seeks again when you release it. Any better way to handle this?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if there's a better way but I ended up discarding mouse clicks by checking if it's on the Thumb.

```
public void SeekBar_PreviewMouseLeftButtonDown(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e) {
    // Only process event if click is not on thumb.
    Thumb Obj = GetSliderThumb(sender as Slider);
    Point Pos = e.GetPosition(Obj);
    if (Pos.X < 0 || Pos.Y < 0 || Pos.X > Obj.ActualWidth || Pos.Y > Obj.ActualHeight) {
        // Immediate seek when clicking elsewhere.
    }
}

public Thumb GetSliderThumb(Slider obj) {
    var track = obj.Template.FindName("PART_Track", obj) as Track;
    return track?.Thumb;
}
```